# Meaning of "holloway"

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context, translation

Does it mean just "hollowed underground way" or there is something else? Word is taken from fantasy text.

Comment: Can you give more details about where and in which context it is used?

Comment: It is used for travel from point A to point B. But there is no direct meaning  of "underground" tipe of transportation. Text refer to warhammer setting.

Comment: Example of the application: "...sending us out along the holloways to get on with our business". Sentence taken from "Pariah" by Den Abnett

Comment: user71305, the **History** section of the article at this link has http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holloway,_London has some information about it.

Comment: Thanks, I've read it already, but maybe missed something.

Comment: Holloway London has a tube (metro / underground) station called Holloway Road Tube Station if that's any help?

Comment: Post with link to wiki gave more information. Wonder why I didn't saw it earlier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holloway_Road_tube_station. There may be more information on the main London underground site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the author was attempting to use a neologism (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neologism) in order to suggest a sense of the archaic.

> “All fantastic genres make some use of fictive neology. Heroic fantasy invents words to evoke the archaic origins of its worlds. Phantasmagoric satire delights in wordplay that simultaneously masks and insinuates the objects of its derision. Gothic and supernatural tales invoke esoteric and folkloric terms to create the sense of a concealed or forgotten past.” – Istvan Csiscery-Ronay, Jr., The Seven Beauties of Science Fiction, p. 13)

It may well be that the presence of real "holloways" is coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

This article at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunken_lane) (available via an above link) has:

> A sunken lane (also hollow way or holloway) is a road which has over
>   time fallen significantly lower than the land on either side. They are
>   created incrementally by erosion, by water and traffic. Some are very
>   ancient with evidence of Roman or Iron Age origins, but others such as
>   the Deep Hill Ruts in the old Oregon Trail at Guernsey, Wyoming
>   developed in the space of a decade or two.

There is one (called the Hollow Way) near Padley Gorge in the English Peak district. It cuts straight across a patch of rough moorland, is rocky, makes 6-footers invisible from the surrounding moorland in the middle, and gets very wet after rain.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from googling the word:

Holloway

HM Prison Holloway is a closed category prison for adult women and Young Offenders, located in the Holloway area of the London Borough of Islington, in north and Inner London, England. The prison is operated by Her Majesty's Prison Service.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holloway_(HM_Prison)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holloway_%28HM_Prison%29)

I did not find the word as a pathway...

Comment: Another example: "...one day, upon the notion of taking a holloway down to Toilgate and entering the marsh beyond..." Which means I think, path instead of place. Some kind of main road across the city. And author used it like synonym for "decisions" or "life path".